# Hide 1st outer repeater in jQuery form repeater

Tags: jquery, nested-repeater

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.outer-repeater').repeater({
                show: function() {
                    $(this).slideDown();
                },
                hide: function (deleteElement) {
                    if(confirm('Outer delete sure?')) {
                        $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
                    }
                },
               
                repeaters: [{
                    selector: '.inner-repeater',
                    hide: function (deleteElement) {
                        if(confirm('Inner delete sure?')) {
                            $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
                        }
                    },
                    show: function() {
                        $(this).slideDown();
                    }
                }]
           
            });
        });
```

I've stuck for 2 days. So here is my questions:

1. How to hide 1st outer repeater after initializing? It will appear only after clicking add button.
2. I receive 2 delete Outer delete confirmation followed by inner delete confirmation when I try delete inner item.
   I've read similar topics but I couldn't figure out in my code. https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater/issues/42

Comment: Solved 1st problem here my new html 
<div data-repeater-item class="outer" style="display:none;">

Answer (score 2):

**For your first question:** "*How to hide 1st outer repeater after initializing? It will appear only after clicking add button.*"

- **Choice #1**

You can add style="display:none;" to your first data-repeater-item Example:

```html
<form class="repeater">
    <div data-repeater-list="group-name">
      <div data-repeater-item style="display:none;">
        ...
        <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

- ***Choice #2***

Another choice is to delete the element

```js
$('#filters_repeater').repeater({
    initEmpty: false,

    show: function () {
        $(this).slideDown();
    },

    hide: function (deleteElement) {
        $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
    }
});

// Delete first element on the repeater as it is only to define the structure to repeat
$('#filters_repeater').find('[data-repeater-delete]').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('.outer-repeater').repeater({
        //--------> just add this here<-------
            initEmpty: true,
        // ------------------------
            show: function() {
                $(this).slideDown();
            },
            hide: function (deleteElement) {
                if(confirm('Outer delete sure?')) {
                    $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
                }
            },
           
            repeaters: [{
                selector: '.inner-repeater',
                hide: function (deleteElement) {
                    if(confirm('Inner delete sure?')) {
                        $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
                    }
                },
                show: function() {
                    $(this).slideDown();
                }
            }]
 
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also add a brief explanation for your solution. This will help the users to understand your solution.